# Laravel Eloquent count on whereIn() 5 relations deep

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need your help because I want to optimize these queries in the less possible...

I want to get the count of alerts which are in :
`companies -> sites -> interventions -> purchases -> alerts`

I want to get the count of actions which are in :
`contractors -> actions`
`companies -> actions`

I do the following but 7 requests on each page is not really good :/

```
$companies = Company::where('id', '=', Auth::user()->userable_id)->orWhere('company_id', '=', Auth::user()->userable_id)->pluck('id')->toArray();
$contractors = Contractor::where('id', '=', Auth::user()->userable_id)->orWhere('company_id', '=', Auth::user()->userable_id)->pluck('id')->toArray();

$cp = array_merge($companies, $contractors);

$sites = Site::whereIn('company_id', $companies)->pluck('id')->toArray();
$interventions = Intervention::whereIn('site_id', $sites)->pluck('id')->toArray();
$purchases = Purchase::whereIn('intervention_id', $interventions)->pluck('id')->toArray();
$bubblecounts['alerts'] = Alerts::whereIn('purchase_id', $purchases)->where('status', 0)->whereDate('alert_date', '!=', '0000-00-00 00:00:00')->count();
$bubblecounts['actions'] = Action::whereIn('actionable_id', $cp)->where([['status', 0], ['alert_date', '!=', null]])->count();
```

Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One optimisation that i can think of quickly is this:

```
$alerts = Alerts::whereIn('purchase_id', $purchases)->where('status', 0)->whereDate('alert_date', '!=', '0000-00-00 00:00:00')->count();
$actions = Action::whereIn('actionable_id', $cp)->where([['status', 0], ['alert_date', '!=', null]])->count();

$bubblecounts['alerts'] = $alerts;
$bubblecounts['actions'] = $actions;
```

rather then fetching the entire rows it only gets the count.if there are large no of alerts and actions you will have a good performance boost.